# The accepted answer styling makes 'votes' invisible in search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, design

See for example this [search query](https://superuser.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1):

> [image: Search query]

'votes' is invisible here -- it's styled a pure white. Also, I believe there should be some border or background on the box surrounding the '2 votes'. Can this please be fixed?

Comment: I'm referring to the word "votes", @fixer1234. See for example in [this search query](http://superuser.com/search?q=is%3Aa) -- it says "0 votes", not just a number.

Comment: Ah ha!  That's actually a better example for your question, because the word "Votes" appears except when it is an accepted answer.  In that case, white is used for the letters, but is invisible without the colored background.

Comment: It looks like the problem happens only if you include a search term that restricts results to answers, like your two examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now

[image]